# Zend Framework headLink() helper and HTML5

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

I have set doctype to HTML 5 like this:

```
$view->doctype('HTML5');
```

Then I have added a stylesheet like this:

```
$view->headLink()->appendStylesheet($view->baseUrl().'/css/reset.css');
```

It produces link tag like this:

```
<link href="/css/reset.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

But for HTML 5 this would be correct, no?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/reset.css">
```

One more question. How to produce meta tag like this with headMeta() helper?

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To produce the tag

`<meta charset="utf-8">`

you can do the following.

`$view->headMeta()->setCharset( 'UTF-8' );`

The link tag produced by Zend is correct as well. The difference is that Zend tries to be more specific.

Go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_link_media.asp) to see the different options for the media tag.

Yours is correct too but the tag Zend displays gives the browser a better idea of how to display you page by telling it what type of display the html document is meant for.